# datepicker from - to and select x-value for set x-month later

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, datepicker, selected

I have an datepicker from - to. 
For the date -to i use an select value (stands for x month later).
My code works only, f.e when i set a number like 6 (date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6 );).
What is wrong?

My code is http://jsfiddle.net/uFcX7/3/

```
$(function (form) {
 var month = $('select[name=GetMes]').val();
 $(".fecha_inicio").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
     onSelect: function (dateText, instance) {
         date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
         date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + month);
         //date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);

         $(".fecha_fin").datepicker("setDate", date);

     }
 });
 $(".fecha_fin").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
 });
```

});

When i use select value, the date are wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem/question is.

Comment: The problem is: When I selected option value 10, than i like to-Date 10 Months later than from Date.

Comment: Look here [http://jsfiddle.net/uFcX7/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/uFcX7/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Javascript month has the range of `0 - 11`. You would need to work out the difference and add a year. For instance:

```
if((date.getMonth() + month) > 11)
```

you will want to add 1 year to the date and then add the difference on months i.e.

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + (month - 11));
```

Comment: Can you share Jsfiddle?

Comment: You didn't completely implement it as I described. Also you were getting the date incorrectly and calling the function at the wrong time. I have fixed most of the issues for you now, however the format of the date isn't as your desire so I would advised you to look up the `Date()` function in JavaScript and `datepicker()` API in jQueryUI. And here is my version of your code to my understanding of what you needed. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFcX7/7/)

Comment: Also in your selection dropdown you had all values after 8 with the value of 8. The logic on your statements wasn't too efficient either if `month > 11` then everything else obviously isn't so you can use `else` instead of another if statement because you will actually be missing the condition when `month == 11`.

Comment: Hello Livewire, thank you for your help. I don`t understand you, way I need to work out the difference and add a year.  Look [http://jsfiddle.net/uFcX7/8/] here, its working now perfectly.

Comment: I didn't know that you could parse a month like that to `datepicker`. What I said makes sense and actually worked as you can see in the version I provided you, sure if you got it to work, that's great. What I provided you was a logical solution. Regardless I still answered your question, which wasn't very detailed in the first place. I think I deserve the credit for providing you with a solution don't you?

Comment: Yes of course, its your credit. Only one more, in your JSFiddel it counts 3 month, when I selected 2. I don't know why? But with your help, I found my solution. Thanks for all.

Comment: date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + (m - 12));